# React onClick method od link with href not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app, I have links with `href` attribute (it is need to open links in new window after right click on link) and on link element is react `onClick` method.

See example here:

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component { 
  handleClick(event) {
   alert('click. but dont redirect...');
    
    return false;
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <a href="test" onClick={this.handleClick}>Test link</a>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

click on link. `onClick` method calls, it is ok, but browser do redirect to page, in `href` attribute and I don't know, how can I prevent it.

Is possible have link with `href` attribute and `onclick` method in React without redirect on to the page in `href` attr?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/77298/).

Comment: sorry, correct link: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/77298/

Comment: if you don't want to redirect then use this: `<a href='#' onClick={this.handleClick}>Test link</a>` don't give any path in `href`.

Comment: I need href attribute if user wants to open link in new window...

Comment: If you do not want to redirect, move `event.preventDefault()` to the top of `handleClick`.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there !!!!
You just need to move

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

up. And it will work !!!!.

Please find below code . Paste it.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component { 
  handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('click. but dont redirect...');

    return false;

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <a href="test" onClick={this.handleClick}>Test link</a>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

in your href try using "javascript:void(0);"

Answer (score 0):

remove preventDefault(); from onClick